# jquery 2 divs children comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 elements ( div ) :

**I**

```
<div id="1">
 <div >
  <img /> <img />
  <span> </span>
   . 
   .
 <div>
 <div>
  <p></p>
  .
  .
 </div> 
 .
 .
</div>
```

**II**

```
<div id="2">
 <div >
  <img />
  <span></span>
  <h1></h1>
  . 
  .
 <div>
 . 
 .
</div>
```

both divs have `different number of child` and those child further have `different number of there subchilds`. **My question** is , i want to compare these 2 div and access all the unsimilar elements present in div#2 in comparison with div#1. How can i do this with using jquery methods and as efficient as possible?

Comment: I have not good knowledge of jquery ,so i used for loops and the code messed up and not good to use and show

Comment: @Sagiv if u can , help me out pls

Comment: So you want to access all elements that are in both, or all that are in 1 but not 2, or 2 but not 1? I'm sorry, the question was a little unclear.

Comment: Access all the elements of div - 2 which is not present in div - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be a good start for you:

```
function compare(o1, o2){
 var arr = [];
 $(o1).each(function(i1){        
     var match = false;
     $(o2).each(function(i2){            
         if ( $("o1:eq("+i1+")").html() == $("o2:eq("+i2+")").html() )
             match = true;
     });
     if ( !match )
         arr.push($("o1:eq("+i1+")")[0]);        
 });
 return arr;
}
```

you go over each element and look for a match. push all the elements that have no match in array and return the array.
note that it compare the first children of each given object.
to call it:

```
var diffs = compare(div1,div2);
```